# TRV visa approved after biometric expired

Tags: schengen, canada, biometric-passports

IRCC Canada sent me an original passport request on September 20, 2023, but my biometrics expired on September 13, 2023.

How could this be? I submitted my passport already, so does this mean they Will send me a new biometrics request?

Comment: Why is this question tagged "Schengen" ?